# Redirect to referer after a POST Request

Tags: scala, redirect, post, playframework-2.0

I have a web application in Play.  The web application consists of several pages.  In every page there is a small flag that enables the user to change the language (locale) from german to english and back.

I handle this with a redirect to referer:

```
  def referer(implicit request: Request[AnyContent]) =
    request.headers.get(REFERER).getOrElse(mainUrl)
  def locale(l: String) = Authenticated { user =>
     implicit request =>
     Redirect(referer).withCookies(Cookie(LANG, if (l == "de" || l == "en") l else "de"))
  }
```

It is working fine.  Well, at least for GET requests.

I have a specific page where the user has to input data in a form.  This form is then POSTed to the server.  Were errors found, the form is displayed again with the error messages, as usual.  Now, if the user wants to change the language (by clicking on the flag), the redirect to referer does not work, because it tries to use a GET request, and Play complains that a GET route does not exist for this method (which is true).

I am solving this by caching the form and defining another method where the form is taken from the cache:

```
# User data is POSTed to the server
POST    /create/insert              controllers.MyCreate.insert()
# After a redirect the cached form is displayed again
GET     /create/insert              controllers.MyCreate.insertGet()
```

It works, but I don't like this solution.  It does not seem normal to have to create another entry in the routes and another method just to adress this problem.  I would need to add this hack for every POST route in my application!

Is there a more elegant solution to this?

Comment: It's bad practice to use referer in your application, more and more browsers do not include it for security reasons.

Comment: Is there an alternative for the problem I describe, apart from referer?  I mean, how can I change the locale and return to the page where the user was?

Answer (score 0):

You could change it into something like this (untested):

```
def changeLang(lang:String, returnUri:String) = Action {
  Redirect(returnUri)
    .withCookies(Cookie(LANG, if (lang == "de" || lang == "en") lang else "de"))
}
```

In you template you would output the route to changeLang in the link, you can get the `uri` via the `request`

```
@routes.Application.changeLang("en", request.uri).url
```

I suggest you make `request` implicit in your action and define it as implicit in your template so you don't need to pass it on to each template.

```
// in the controller
def myUrl = Action { implicit request =>
  Ok(views.html.myTemplate("something"))
}

// in the template
@(title:String)(implicit request:play.api.mvc.RequestHeader)
```

---

### Edit

As for the POST requests, it common (for these types of framework) to have POST requests simple handle stuff and then redirect to another page. The usual flow is like this:

- Form submits to a handler
- Handler does something with the form information
- Handler redirects to a page

An example:

```
// Hooked up to a GET route
def edit(id:Long) = Action {
   // render the view with a form that displays the element with given id
   // if the flash scope contains validation information, use that in display
}

// Hooked up to a POST route
def editHandler = Action {
   // validate the form
   // if validation succeeds
     // persist the object
     // redirect to edit
   // else
     // put the form information into the flash scope
     // put any validation messages into the flash scope
     // redirect to edit
}
```

If you do not want to use this flow you need to have both a GET and POST route anyway. The user might do a page reload on the resulting page.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about something similar.  In this way you have the original url sent to the method, and you don't need to resort to the (maybe not present) referer feature.  But the original question is still there:  What could I do for POST requests?

Comment: If this is just for one page, maybe use jquery to override the submit of the language change form. Have it grab the language value and copy it to a hidden input on the main page's form and submit that form. In your controller just check whether the language field is set. Normally it would be blank, but if it's not then change the language and you can render the page again with the other form data intact.