# Pattern for redirecting to previous page after an action

Tags: scala, redirect, playframework, playframework-2.1

In my Play app, I have several actions (e.g. "Delete" an entity) that can be triggered from different pages. After the action is triggered, I'd like to redirect the user back to the page they were on before I performed the action. Is there a good pattern to use for this in Play?

Comment: are you looking for something better than retrieving the referer via request.getHeader and storing it in either flash or session?  I would be interested in hearing about better ways as well.  Update: just realized you asked about scala.

Comment: @alihaider I've pasted the solution I used below, but maybe using the referrer would be better?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891988/redirect-to-referer-after-a-post-request

Answer (score 5):

you can easily use `@request.getHeader("referer")` in your Templates, for example if you have a cancel button that should redirect you to the previous page, use this :

```
<a  href="@request.getHeader("referer")">Cancel</a>
```

in this way, you don't need to pass any extra information to your templates.  (tested with play 2.3.4)

Answer (score 2):

This is what I came up with in the end, although it isn't particularly elegant, and I'd be interested in better ways of doing it. I added a hidden input to my form with the current page URL:

```
@(implicit request: RequestHeader)

...

<form action="@routes.Controller.doStuff()" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="previousURL" value="@request.uri"/>
  ...
</form>
```

Then in my controller:

```
def doStuff() = Action { implicit request =>
  val previousURLOpt: Option[String] =
    for {
      requestMap <- request.body.asFormUrlEncoded
      values <- requestMap.get("previousURL")
      previousURL <- values.headOption
    } yield previousURL
   previousURLOpt match {
     case Some(previousURL) =>
       Redirect(new Call("GET", previousURL))
     case None =>
       Redirect(routes.Controller.somewhereElse)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I've found to do this, is from within your controller method, use this:

```
String refererUrl = request().getHeader("referer");
```

So, you'd do something like:

```
public static Result query(String queryStr, int page, int offset) {
    String refererUrl = request().getHeader("referer");
    Logger.info("refererUrl: " + refererUrl);
    if(queryStr.length() < 3) {
        flash(Application.FLASH_ERROR_KEY, "type a longer search than '" + queryStr.trim() + "'");
        return redirect(refererUrl);
    }
    return ok(listings.render(searchService.searchListings(queryStr)));
}
```

Keep in mind you need to do a redirect() and NOT a render() with a flash message.